# How can I solve the following saddle point optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

The function $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}):\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined as
$f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{Bx}$, where $\mathbf{x}\in \mathcal{P}, \mathbf{y}\in \mathcal{Q}$. $\mathcal{P},\mathcal{Q}$ are convex polytopes.
I want to find a saddle point  $(\mathbf{x}^*,\mathbf{y}^*)$ such that $f (\mathbf{x}^*,\mathbf{y})\geq f(\mathbf{x}^*,\mathbf{y}^*)\geq f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}^*)$, where $\forall \mathbf{x}\in \mathcal{P}, \forall \mathbf{y}\in \mathcal{Q}$.

Can I solve such problem by just solving the following min max or max min problem?

$\min\limits_{\mathbf{y}\in \mathcal{Q}}\max\limits_{\mathbf{x}\in \mathcal{P}}f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$  and $\max\limits_{\mathbf{x}\in \mathcal{P}}\min\limits_{\mathbf{y}\in \mathcal{Q}}f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$.

Suppose that such saddle point must exists for our problem.

Comment: what are the dimensions of B?

Comment: Necessarily $1 \times n$...

Comment: just making sure

Comment: the dimension of matrix B is n*n

Comment: When B is n*n, Bx is a vector, right?

Answer (score 1):

A polytope is bounded. Your function $f$ is convex-concave (convex in $x$ for fixed $y$ and vice versa). The function therefore has a (unique) saddle point (by, e.g., Lemma 37.3.2 in Convex Analysis by Rockafellar). Both your min-max formulations will find it.

Answer (score 1):

$\min \max = \max \min$ by [Sion's minimax theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sion%27s_minimax_theorem), since $\mathcal P$ is compact. In particular, you don't need $\mathcal Q$ to be compact.